# python find the specific element position and return all distinct elements in front of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python list:

```
a = [('x',3.6),('x',5.2),('y',4.5),('x',1.4),('y',2.1),('z',3.3)]
```

In `a`, I want to find top2 distinct element of `a` which sorted by the second element, which means:

First: I sorted `a`:

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

`b: [('x', 5.2), ('x', 3.6), ('y', 3.5), ('z', 3.3), ('y', 2.1), ('x', 1.4)]`

Second: in the sorted `b`, I need get two distinct element, which result may be: `['x', 'y']`, how can I get this result neatly?

ADDED:

and if I have a list:

```
a = [('x',3.6, 'xx1'),('x',5.2, 'xx2'),('y',4.5, 'xx1'),('x',1.4, 'xx3'),('y',2.1, 'xx1'),('z',3.3, 'xx2')]
```

and `b`:

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

how can I get the top2 distinct elements(which result may be `['x', 'y']`) of a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) and get the first 2 elements of its keys

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
list(OrderedDict(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)).keys())[:2]
Out[7]: ['x', 'y']
```

---

For more elements in each item of `a`, need to reformat the structure of elements of tuple when building the `OrderedDict` in a format of `(key, (item1, item2, ...))`

```py
list(OrderedDict([(x[0], (x[1], x[2]) )for x in sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]))[:2]
Out[10]: ['x', 'y']
```

Comment: this can solve the specific problem, but in reality, I have a tuple of 4 elements, and how can I solve it?

Comment: there are so many possibilities, pls show us the sample data. you may start a new question if it changed a lot

Comment: I have added content